# Use of Percentile with condition in Kusto

Tags: azure, azure-data-explorer, kql, kusto-explorer, kusto-java-sdk

I'm looking to use percentile() in kusto with certain condition
here's the data I have,

```
OnStatus| OffStatus | WebId | UserId |
true    | false     | 1     | A123   |
true    | false     | 2     | A123   |
true    | false     | 3     | A123   |
false   | true      | 4     | A123   |
false   | true      | 1     | B123   |
false   | true      | 2     | B123   |
false   | true      | 3     | B123   |
false   | true      | 4     | B123   |
```

Here's what I need : unique row for each user with P50 & P95 of the status looking at all the WebIds

Step1:

```
UserId | P50_StatusOn | P95_StatusOn | P50_StatusOff | P95_StatusOff |
A123   | true         | false        | false         | false         |
B123   | false        | false        | true          | true          |
```

Step2:

```
| P50_StatusOnCnt | P95_StatusOnCnt | P50_StatusOffCnt | P95_StatusOffCnt |
| 1               | 0               | 1                |  1               |
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what you could do for step 1:

```
let T = datatable(UserId:string, OnStatus:bool, OffStatus:bool)
[
   "A123", true, false,
   "A123", true, false,
   "A123", true, false,
   "A123", false, false,
   "B123", false, true,
   "B123", false, true,
   "B123", false, true,
   "B123", false, true,
];
T
| summarize
    P50_StatusOn = percentile(OnStatus, 50), 
    P95_StatusOn = percentile(OnStatus, 95),
    P50_StatusOff = percentile(OffStatus, 50), 
    P95_StatusOff = percentile(OffStatus, 95)
by UserId
```

and then for the second step simply add:

```
| summarize sum(P50_StatusOn), sum(P95_StatusOn), sum(P50_StatusOff), sum(P95_StatusOff)
```